# How can 'gamma-squared' be a 'linear term' in the Kadowacki-Woods ratio?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, electrons, fermions

[image]

A linear term, by definition, is not squared, correct?

And isn't lowercase gamma a ratio of specific heat under constant pressure to specific heat under constant volume?  Why is that here?  Why squared?

I don't get it.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0805.4275.pdf

The Wikipedia article may just be written a bit unclearly. $\gamma$ is the coefficient that determines how the heat capacity depends linearly on the temperature, $C = \gamma T$, and then it is squared. Similarly, the "quadratic term" is from $\rho = \rho_{0} + AT^{2}$, so more explicitly, A is the coefficient of the quadratic term in the expansion of $\rho(T)$.